# One component overlapping on other in react.js app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router, react-component

I want to render my login.js component on app.js file as usual, but today I'm facing a problem like one component in the react-router overlap into the other though each of them is a separate component in my react.js project. I actually do not understand why this problem arises suddenly.

This is my component which I am going to render on my App.js file inside the react-router.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Login.css";

    const Login = () => {
      return (
        <div className="login_area">
          <div className="form_part">Hello World</div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Login;
```

CSS of this component is below....

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.login_area {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    url(../../images/Authentication/photo-1.jpeg)
  );
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form_part {
  width: 380px;
  height: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6% auto;
  background: darkolivegreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Finally, This is my App.js file where I render all the components inside the react-router...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import React from 'react';
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar.js";

import Home from "./components/home/Home";
import Footer from "./components/footer/Footer";
import About from "./components/about/About";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./components/authentication/Login";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/home">
              <Home></Home>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about">
              <About></About>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signin">
              <Login></Login>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/achievement"></Route>
            <Route path="/books"></Route>
            <Route path="/tutorials"></Route>
            <Route path="/blog"></Route>
          </Switch>
          <Footer></Footer>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my snippet in browser click on the below link

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Wsn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8LNq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should have making change  some on css file which are following.....

Now it fix ....

```
login_area {
  /* background: #f6f5f7; */
  background-image: url("../../images/Authentication/photo-1.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  /* margin: -20px 0 50px; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple routes defined for your app's routing, enclosed with Switch component like this;

```
<Switch>

  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/detail" component={Detail} />

  <Route exact path="/functions" component={Functions} />
  <Route path="/functions/:functionName" component={FunctionDetails} />

</Switch>
```

hen you have to put `exact` keyword to the Route which it's path is also included by another Route's path. For example home path `/` is included in all paths so it needs to have `exact` keyword to differentiate it from other paths which start with `/`. The reason is also similar to `/`functions path. If you want to use another route path like /functions-detail or /functions/open-door which includes /functions in it then you need to use `exact` for the /functions route.

Comment: Its not workd, I have only used path="/signin" once no other component's path similar like this

Comment: Do you have any other solution Hithesh k?

Comment: <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />  use `exact`  because  `/` is common in all the routes

Comment: I tried using exact keyword but the result is same still overlapping